# Obtaining results from operations on multiple files as a two-column matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I'm using a for-loop to loop through files in a directory. Then I do a set of processing on the data in each file and write a matrix with 10 rows.
This is my code.

```
for(i in 1:length(testData))
      {
        MAE[1,i] = abs(forecastData$mean[i] - testData[i])
      }
```

Now I wish to wish to do the following:

- add the rows in this matrix
- write it as a value in a separate two column matrix with the filename being the first column and the value as the second column
- sort it as per the value(not filename)
- access it globally(i.e, outside the for loop that iterates through the directory).

The number of rows for this matrix will be the total number of files in the directory(dynamically assigned is what I mean). How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: Can I ask why you are using a loop? Are you familiar with the functionality in the built-in function `list.files()`? Also, please provide a MWE that includes some sample data.

Comment: @TARehman I need to write the filename which is stored in a variable k against the total of the forloop mentioned here in  a matrix

Comment: I've added in an edit for your question that make it more clear (I hope). I wrote a general answer for you below, but you are really asking about a few different tasks (sorting, etc). Hopefully my answer is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to give a comprehensive answer because there is no example. In general, however, I would use `list.files()` to obtain a vector of all the files in question, and then write a function that performed whatever math you need done on each file. Such a function could look something like this.

```
func.file_math <- function(file.name) {

    <insert file operations>
    return(list(file.name=file.name,
                number=number))
}
```

Using `sapply()` you could then run this over all the contents of your `file.list()`. Once done, you can simply use `do.call()` and `rbind.data.frame` to get a data frame of the results.

```
yourfiles <- list.files("/some/path/")
file_math <- sapply(X=yourfiles,
                    FUN=func.file_math,
                    simplify=FALSE,
                    USE.NAMES=TRUE)
file_math.df <- do.call(what=rbind.data.frame,
                        args=file_math)
```